# Variables in initState() not initialized

Tags: flutter, parameter-passing

```
class RoutePage extends StatefulWidget {
 final LatLng? pickUp;
 final LatLng? dropOff;

 RoutePage({required this.pickUp, required this.dropOff});

 @override
 _RoutePage createState() => _RoutePage();
}

class _RoutePage extends State<RoutePage> {
 Set<Marker> _markers = {};
 LatLng _origin;
 LatLng _destination;

 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   final _origin = widget.pickUp;
   final _destination = widget.dropOff;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
}
```

In my code, despite that I have initialized _origin and _destination in the initState(), I still get the error message "Non-nullable instance field '_origin' must be initialized." Adding late does not work too... I also tried adding setState, but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to have two variables with the same values? Since `LatLng _origin` would be the same as `LatLng? pickUp`, you could just call `widget.pickUp` within `_RoutePage` if `_origin` never changes.

Comment: hmm, ouh yea didnt thought of that, thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables are not initialised because you are recreating them inside the `initState()` function:

```
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 final _origin = widget.pickUp; // <-- Recreating _origin here
 final _destination = widget.dropOff; // <-- Recreating _destination here
}
```

It is allowed to have variables with the same name in Dart because inside functions you have a different scope. Thus, you get no error here, but since you are using the `final` keyword, you are recreating those variables. To resolve this, do not use final inside your `initState()` function:

```
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _origin = widget.pickUp; // <-- Assigning a value to _origin here
 _destination = widget.dropOff; // <-- Assigning a value to _destination here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

**final** properties are assigned either via named constructor parameters or at declaration, not in the **initState** method.

You could initialize them via the named constructor parameters like this:

```dart
class RoutePage extends StatefulWidget {
 final LatLng? pickUp;
 final LatLng? dropOff;
 
 RoutePage({required this.pickUp, required this.dropOff});
 
 @override
 _RoutePage createState() => _RoutePage(origin: pickUp, destination: dropOff);
}

class _RoutePage extends State<RoutePage> {
 Set<Marker> _markers = {};
 final LatLng? origin;
 final LatLng? destination;
  
 _RoutePage({ this.origin, this.destination });

 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // ... 
 }
}
```

Or don't set them final at all and then you can assign them via the **initState**. My two cents.

Comment: Don't pass variables to the state directly via the constructor, since it does not guarantee the widget gets rebuilt when state is updated. You should access parameters from the state itself via widget.variable. More info here: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/no_logic_in_create_state.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `pickUp, dropOff` variables are typed as `LatLng?` then you are trying to assign to another variable type as `LatLng`
2. In `initState` you are again creating variables.

updated code(above things are updated in the below code):

```
class RoutePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final LatLng? pickUp;
  final LatLng? dropOff;

  RoutePage({required this.pickUp, required this.dropOff});

  @override
  _RoutePage createState() => _RoutePage();
}

class _RoutePage extends State<RoutePage> {
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  LatLng? _origin;
  LatLng? _destination;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _origin = widget.pickUp;
    _destination = widget.dropOff;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: @supperr-coder don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if the answer is worked for you.